# how to assign primary key of a model to the index of a list?

Tags: r, .net

I want my CustomerID in my option value to bind to CustomerSales at new Primary key

generated(CustomerSaleID) so each new row generated in CustomerSales i add for it CustomerID at the

new primary key and what about SaleID how can i bind it to CustomerSales and the Sale is not

submitted yet

```
related to create view in Sales:
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Customer" class="control-label">Customer</label>
    <select asp-for="CustomerSales[/*CustomerSaleID*/].CustomerID" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select a customer</option>
    
    @foreach (var c in ViewBag.Customer.CustomerSales)
    {
        <option value="c.Customer.CustomerID">
            c.Customer.FirstName
            c.Customer.LastName
        </option>
    }

</select>
<span asp-validation-for="Customer.CustomerID" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace UserSales.Models
{
    public class CustomerSale
    {
    public int CustomerSaleID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public Customer? Customer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Sale")]
    public int? SaleID { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
namespace UserSales.Models
{


public class Sale
{

    public int SaleID { get; set; }
    public DateTime SaleDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public Item SoldItem { get; set; }  
    public List<ItemSale> ItemSales { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerSale> CustomerSales { get; set; }
    }
    }

namespace UserSales.Models
{
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerSale>? CustomerSales { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
related to Sale Controller:
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
List<Customer> customers = await _context.Customers
    .Include(c => c.CustomerSales) // Include related CustomerSales if needed
    .ToListAsync();

List<Item> soldItems = await _context.Items
    .Include(i => i.ItemSales) // Include related ItemSales if needed
    .ToListAsync();

// Set the retrieved Customer and Item in the Sale object
ViewBag.Customer = customers;
ViewBag.SoldItem = soldItems;

return View();
```

}

I tried to search on a solution for it but no resource found that solve my problem